# How to return a value from a function

Tags: node.js, express, arangodb, arangojs

I have an ArangoDB function that queries all the `documents` in the `instanceCollection`, inside `databasehelper.js`:

```
listInstances = function listInstances() {
    var instances = db.query(aqlQuery`
    FOR doc in instanceCollection
    RETURN doc
    `).then(
        cursor => cursor.all()
    ).then(
        result => {
            return result;
        }
    )
    return instances;
}
```

Also, I want to use this function to reflect the JSON query to an Express API:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var allInstances = databasehelper.listInstances();
    res.send(allInstances);
});
```

The api result was nothing but an empty JSON `{}`.
How can I reflect the result of my ArangoDB query to my Express API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand how promises work. The following is an idea on how it should be designed.

databasehelper.js => Return a promise

```
listInstances = function listInstances() {
    return db.query(`some query`)
    .then(cursor => cursor.all())
}
```

in the route, => fetch the data from the promise

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    databasehelper.listInstances()
    .then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    })
});
```